# How do i use "if" and "and" condition in R data frame

Tags: r, if-statement

I want to update in "Remark" column using condition on other multiple columns

```
RBNRFinal$Remarks<- ifelse(RBNRFinal$restock_date != "NA","Restock Done"," ") # this works fine

RBNRFinal$Remarks<- ifelse(RBNRFinal$Remarks == " " & RBNRFinal$dispatched_flag == 1,"GP Done"," ") # dont get " GP Done" values
```

please help me in using correct "IF" and "And" or & condition in the data frame.

Comment: Can you pleas share some test data for us: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: The code seems fine, probably the data is not what you think it is